# Deprecated properties in PFLogInView(Controller)

Tags: ios, parse-platform, deprecated, pfloginviewcontroller

Compiling an iOS app that has now been running for a while, I see the following about the properties: signUpLabel and externalLogInLabel

```
signUpLabel
The sign up label. (Deprecated: This property is deprecated and will always be nil.)

externalLogInLabel
The facebook/twitter login label. (Deprecated: This property is deprecated and will always be nil.)
```

There must be some good reasons for those properties to be deprecated.
But what do we do instead of using them? Meaning how do we change the code inside the working app?